# What is the DPT_ENTRY_LOCK wait type?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2016, wait-types

We have a SQL Server 2016 Availability Group with 3 servers.  Twice in the past 5 days we have had performance issues.  8a is our primary server, and 8b and 8c are the secondaries.

We started having issues right before 8PM.  We saw timeouts as well as 502 Bad Gateway errors.  On 8b and 8c we see a huge spike in `DPT_ENTRY_LOCK` waits as well an increase in `LCK_M_IS`, `LCK_M_S`, and `HADR_SYNC_COMMIT` on the primary at the same time.  Unfortunately we don't know which server of the 3 was timing out because all 3 sit behind a load balancer for read-only connections.

We are currently trying to track down what was locking stuff up but can't figure out what the `DPT_ENTRY_LOCK` type is on the secondaries.  When [SQL Skills](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/dpt_entry_lock/) doesn't have the answer I start to worry.

[image: Wait Chart]

Comment: Complete guess?  Dispatch Pool Thread?  My limited understanding is that the dispatcher is used for background processes.  If you've got an Availability Group, this could be the wait for getting the replicas up to date.  Similar to some of the mirror waits.  It's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DPT_ENTRY_LOCK` waits are caused when the workload is constantly modifying the same pages (so constant updates would cause this to show up). Practically nothing has been written around this subject so trying to get definitive answers (along with supporting evidence) is more than a challenge, as such I'll give you what I've seen from experience on my side. You would probably need to open a CSS call at this point for something more definitive.

When you have a large number of transaction on your primary that have to be flushed to the secondary, and you have a high number of reads on a secondary that access the same tables, you end up with this lock, or a `DIRTY_PAGE_TABLE_LOCK` wait.

These happen when there is a lot of work going on, meaning that there are a large number of dirty pages that need to be flushed, expect to see very short wait times on this usually. You wouldn't expect this thanks to RCSI on the secondary, but it happens, and I've only seen it in the case where there are a large number of writes on the primary and read calls on the secondary.

As for a way around this, you could try using indirect checkpoints (if not already enabled) which uses sorted, partitioned lists to track dirty pages rather than the random ordering used by prior versions - see [SQL 2016 – It Just Runs Faster: Indirect Checkpoint Default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bobsql/2016/06/03/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-indirect-checkpoint-default/)

There is a possibility that this could cause unforeseen performance issues on your primary, so you should test it at load prior to implementing on a production system. And there is no guarantee that this will work. I'm actually about to try this very thing for some systems that I'm experiencing the same issues with.

You might expect to see `PARALLEL_REDO_TRAN_TURN` waits as well, which are caused by page splits.

Comment: We figured out what caused it. We do index reorgs on this server periodically (let’s not get into that). Occasionally, when reorganizing an index on a heavily read table the DPT_ENTRY_LOCK and DIRTY_PAGE_TABLE_LOCK waits would skyrocket and we would see the redo queue get backed up. We would also get the timeouts and connection errors. This would also not correct itself after the reorg as it normally does until we killed connections to the affected server. We can rebuild or reorg indexes on tables that are less frequently read from.

Comment: We are using indirect checkpoints to see if this helps. Using those seemed to help in our dev environment but they don't tend to act exactly the same.